# Why can't I visit a specific site?

Tags: google-chrome, internet, browser, safari, web

For some reason I can't visit http://daringfireball.net and it's driving me crazy. On Chrome I get "This webpage is not available ERR_TIMED_OUT", on Safari I get "..the server where this page is located isn't responding". It has worked previously but this has been going on for a while.

Here's what I've checked so far:

- http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/ says it's just me
- Cleared cookies/cache
- Verified it's not re-directed in /private/etc/hosts

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did the website ever work?

Comment: Telnet tto it. Enter a mahuial HHTP request. If/when that fails then you know the problem is not due to a local program.  (but e.g. due to misconfigured routing at your ISP or local CDN).

Comment: When all else fails, take a packet capture.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend trying these in the order posted.

1. Make sure there are no parental control type programs blocking access.
2. If you have cookies disabled that could prevent you from connecting.
3. You could try Tor browser as it doesn't have many restrictions.
4. Try clearing browsing cookies.
5. Another method is restarting your router (completely cycle power) in case there's an error there.
6. You could also try changing your IP to make sure the site didn't accidentally flag you.
7. Try opening CMD and running `ipconfig /flushdns`
8. DO THIS AT YOUR OWN RISK! If you are not too experienced with stuff like this, I would skip this step. You don't want to screw up other connections. The "hosts" file maps IP's to hostnames. In `C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc` there is a file called "hosts". You want to open this file with notepad, copy all the text, and delete it. Then create a new text document, name it hosts, and paste all the text inside. Then remove the file extension when you save it so it saves as a file and not a .txt file.
9. If nothing else works, contact the webmaster. Get their info from http://www.who.is/

Comment: Sorry I know I mentioned clearing cookies again, but you might try it through a third-party software like CCleaner just to be sure everything cleared.

Comment: Sometimes clearing the hosts file completely can help.